# Why can't I use ES6 import/export in Rollup config files?

Tags: javascript, node.js, rollup

In the rollup docs, there is a basic tutorial to get your first bundle created. There is a note:

> Note: Rollup itself processes the config file, which is why we're able
>   to use export default syntax – the code isn't being transpiled with
>   Babel or anything similar, so you can only use ES2015 features that
>   are supported in the version of Node.js that you're running.

I hate when I am following something quite nicely and then reach a sentence or two that I don't comprehend completely. This is the case for this snippet.

The tutorial example shows I can write my config using ES6 module syntax. "Rollup itself processes the config file", is this a precise statement or does it simply mean that Rollup does something under the hood? "the code isn't being transpiled", "you can only use ES2015 features that are supported in the version of node you are using", so does this mean that the under the hood is that Rollup is using node to process the config file? But I thought node didn't have support for ES6 modules yet.

Can someone explain this snippet in a more precise way laying out exactly and exhaustively what it implies?

Comment: It simply means that Rollup manually parses the config file without using any fancy node.js features or a transpiler like Babel. As such, Rollup's support for the export syntax is hardcoded into rollup by its programmer (again, not depending on any javascript feature, Rollup could have been written in PHP and it would still support the export syntax because Rollup's programmer wrote code to parse it). But, any other feature that comes from ES6 such as classes and destructuring requires you use Node.js or a transpiler that supports it because Rollup's developers did not write code for it

Comment: I thought it is pretty clear that "itself processes" informally mean "hey, I'm the guy who wrote Rollup and I wrote code to read every byte in your file and I manually and personally wrote code to manually parse it"

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I think that stuff is implied, but not everyone can understand what is implied always, especially about implementation.

Answer (score 0):

In fact, Rollup **does** transpile config file into commonjs format before executing it. It just doesn't save it into a file, but keeps it in memory.

It converts all `import`s into `require`s.

You can see it easily if you run rollup in a debugger.

You have to set a breakpoint in the very beginning of `rollup.config.js` file. Start debugger and wait until stopped on the breakpoint, then you will see the source code of a generated in-memory copy of your `rollup.config.js`, not the original one.